# How to Close Github Issues in Go

Tags: go

I know how to create an issue using [go-github](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-github/github)

```
    ctx := context.Background()
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(
        &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: "xxxxxxxxx"},
    )
    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)
    client := github.NewClient(tc)
    title := "title"
    body := "body"
    opt := &github.IssueRequest{
        Title: &title,
        Body:  &body,
    }
    client.Issues.Create(context.Background(), "owner", "repo", opt)
```

However, the GoDoc does not show how to close an issue.

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: There is a State field in the Issue struct. Might be just that.

Comment: I was able to do this by setting State to closed.
Thanks!